# Using paths from a function that uses globbing

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards, function

It is known that parsing the output of ls is [generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and one solution is to use globbing instead of ls to 'safely' loop through files in a directory.

```
for path in /path/to/search/*; do
    ...
    # Do more filtering
    ...
    echo "$path"
done
```

This function will further filter some of the results that the glob matches and outputs the remaining paths.

However if I want to reuse this logic elsewhere can I use it's output via a function safely and loop that?

```
function myglob() {
    for path in /path/to/search/*; do
        ...
        # Do more filtering
        ...
        echo "$path"
    done
}

function myExample() {
    results=$(myglob)
    for i in "$results"; do
        echo "$i"
    done
}
```

Or must I always duplicate the glob logic and make minor changes to the logic inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't reuse the loops output as you have show as that replicates the issue with `ls` exactly, as well as adds issues with `echo` possibly interpreting backslashes in filenames.

Instead, if you're using a shell language that has arrays and name references (like in `bash` 4.3+), you can do it slightly differently:

```bash
myglob () {
   declare -n list="$1"

   list=( /path/to/search/* )
}

myexample () {
    local results=()
    myglob results

    for pathname in "${results[@]}"; do
        printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
    done

    # or shorter, just
    # printf '%s\n' "${results[@]}"
}
```

Here, the `myglob` function takes the name of a variable in `list`, which is a name reference variable.  This means that any use of `list` will in fact use the named variable.  The function simply expands the glob and stores the result in `list` as if it was an array.

The `myexample` function then calls `myglob` with the string `results`. The `list` variable in `myglob` will therefore reference the `results` variable, and store the expanded pattern in it.

The function then goes on to use `results` as an array of items.

If `myglob` needs to do filtering:

```bash
myglob () {
    declare -n list="$1"

    list=()
    for pathname in /path/to/search/*; do
        # decide whether to use "$pathname" or not
        # then, if it is to be used,
        list+=( "$pathname" )
    done
}
```

That is, loop over the expanded pattern and append items to the list if they are to be returned to the caller.

Comment: I can understand the issue repeating when using `printf` or `echo -e` but I thought `echo` without the `-e` flag would not interpret the special chars like return etc? Is this not the case?

Comment: @myol It depends. See [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)